# Significato di "capelli spiritati"

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel racconto *Superino* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Te lo ricordi questo guardiacaccia?
>    
>         Lo ricordavo chiaramente, sebbene l’avessi visto pochissime volte e fossero trascorsi tre anni. Era sui cinquant’anni, piccolo e secco, la testa fortemente ossuta, con rari **capelli** ritti e **spiritati**, l’occhio vivo ma sempre torto, il naso perennemente escoriato e sotto le narici tenebrose uno sputino di baffo.

Non sono sicura di capire il significato di questi "capelli spiritati" che appaiono nel testo. Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spiritato) ho trovato questa accezione dell'aggettivo "spiritato":

> dell’aspetto e dei gesti che rivelano una grande agitazione e inquietudine interiore, e insieme, spesso, una estrema vivacità: *occhi s., faccia s.; una bionda dagli occhi belli e s.* (Pratolini)

È questo il significato di "spiritato" nel brano? Cioè, i capelli del guardiacaccia avevano un aspetto vivace?

Mi sa però che "spiritato" è usato in questo testo con una connotazione negativa. Siccome "spiritato" in senso proprio vuol dire "indemoniato", il significato nel testo potrebbe essere che i capelli ritti davano un aspetto maligno a questo guardiacaccia, un po' come si fosse stato indemoniato?

---

**Aggiornamento:**

Sui [Neologismi della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pixellato_%28Neologismi%29/) si trova una citazione di *La Repubblica* in cui si può leggere:

> il comico Michael Richards, il personaggio dai capelli spiritati in «Seinfeld»

Questo passaggio fa riferimento al personaggio che si può vedere in [questa fotografia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmo_Kramer#/media/File%3ACosmo_Kramer.jpg), che ha una pettinatura con i capelli arruffati e scomposti. È questo il significato di "capelli spiritati"?

Comment: No, nulla di maligno, soltanto capelli che non stanno al loro posto: ***spiritato*** per estens., *dell’aspetto e dei gesti che rivelano una grande agitazione e inquietudine interiore, e insieme, spesso, una estrema vivacità*. (Treccani). I capelli di Boris Johnson potrebbero essere descritti come spiritati. https://www.occhionotizie.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Boris-Johnson-Brexit-650x409.png

Comment: Anche sui [Neologismi della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pixellato_%28Neologismi%29/) si trova: "il comico Michael Richards, il personaggio dai capelli spiritati in «Seinfeld»".

Comment: Si riferisce a [questo personaggio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmo_Kramer#/media/File%3ACosmo_Kramer.jpg).

Comment: Quindi, @Gio, si tratterebbe semplicemente di capelli scomposti?

Comment: Lo parafraserei con “capelli da matto”, e quindi appunto scomposti, disordinati, portati come capita.

Answer (score 2):

Per [spiritato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spiritato/) Treccani riporta:

> **spiritato** agg. e s. m. (f. -a) [part. pass. di spiritare]. – In senso proprio, ossesso, invasato dal demonio o in genere da uno
>   spirito maligno: un uomo s., una donna s.; chi aveva crisi
>   epilettiche, in passato, era ritenuto s.; una figliola di Lodovico
>   settimo re di Francia era s. (Machiavelli); come sost., individuo
>   invasato dal demonio: esorcizzare uno s., gli s.; essendosi per uso
>   introdotto che da soli sacerdoti siano gli s. scongiurati (Sarpi).
>   Frequente con uso fig., di chi si trova e mostra di essere in uno
>   stato di grande eccitazione, fuori di sé, profondamente sconvolto e
>   agitato: Gervaso, spiritato, gridava e saltellava (Manzoni); «Chi
>   vengono?» fece Drogo, stupito di vedere il caposarto così spiritato
>   (Buzzati); per estens., dell’aspetto e dei gesti che rivelano una
>   grande agitazione e inquietudine interiore, e insieme, spesso, una
>   estrema vivacità: occhi s., faccia s.; una bionda dagli occhi belli e
>   s. (Pratolini); hanno connotazione simile alcune espressioni in cui la
>   parola, usata come sost., e con il sign. proprio è termine di
>   similitudine: sembrare uno s., una s.; parlare, agitarsi come uno s.;
>   fare, avere un viso da s., occhi da spiritato. Con sign. non negativo,
>   pieno di vita, di energia; molto vivace e dinamico: quella ragazza è
>   s., non sta mai ferma; come sost.: è uno s., lavora per dieci!

Nel contesto da te citato il significato non è un quello negativo di indemoniato, ma molto vivace e dinamico, nonostante l’aspetto.

Nel caso dei capelli significa ritti e scomposti.

Comment: Grazie della risposta, @abarisone, ma non riesco a vedere quale sia l'obiettivo di questa lunga citazione del vocabolario Treccani che include quella che ho scritto io nella domanda. Inoltre, cosa ha a che vedere l'essere vivaci e dinamici con il fatto di avere capelli ritti e scomposti?

Comment: Per di più, il personaggio che appare nella fotografia del link che ho messo nel mio commento precedente, qualificato nell'articolo della Treccani come "il personaggio dai capelli spiritati in «Seinfeld»", ha i capelli scomposti ma non precisamente ritti. Quindi, "capelli spiritati" non implica necesariamente "capelli ritti", no?

Comment: Andiamo per ordine: la citazione completa serviva per mostrare che ci sono usi con valenza positiva, visto che sembrava avessi dubbi sul fatto che il termine avesse solo significato negativo. Inoltre ho scritto ritti e scomposti perché appunto i capelli non sono pettinati e sono disposti, passami l'espressione, da "professore matto".

Comment: Grazie, @abarisone. Non avevo dubbi sul fatto che il termine avesse solo significato negativo, quello che avevo scritto è che avevo la sensazione che nel testo di Fenoglio avesse una valenza negativa.